# Get field from JSON object using jq and command line argument

Tags: json, bash, jq

Assume the following JSON file

```
{ 
   "foo": "hello",
   "bar": "world"
}
```

I want to get the `foo` field from the JSON object in a standalone object, and I do this:

```
<file jq '{foo}'
{
   "foo": "hello"
}
```

Now the field I actually want is coming from the shell and is given to `jq` as an argument like this:

```
<file jq --arg myarg "foo" '{$myarg}'
{
   "myarg": "foo"
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't give the expected result `{"foo":"hello"}`.
Any idea why the name of the variable gets into the object?

A workaround to this is to explicitly defined the object:

```
<file jq '{($myarg):.[$myarg]}'
```

Fine, but is there a way to use the shortcut syntax as explained in the man page, but with a variable ?

> You can use this to select particular fields of an object: if the input is an object with “user”, “title”, “id”, and “content” fields and you just want “user” and “title”, you can write
>
> `{user: .user, title: .title}`
>
> Because that is so common, there’s a shortcut syntax for it: `{user, title}`.

*If that matters, I'm using jq version 1.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. The shortcut syntax can only be used under very special conditions. For example, it cannot be used with key names that are jq [keywords](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/How-to:-Avoid-Pitfalls#keywords).

### Alternatives

The method described in the Q is the preferred one, but for the record, here are two alternatives:

```
jq --arg myarg "foo" '
  .[$myarg] as $v | {} | .[$myarg] = $v'
```

And of course there's the alternative that comes with numerous caveats:

```
myarg=foo ; jq "{ $myarg }"
```

Comment: `keys` is not a jq keyword. `if` is one of them. See update.